# Get Ad user Created date

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to export various user data, but I'm having trouble with the "created date"
I'm using:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * –Properties DisplayName, givenName, sn, SamAccountName, Enabled, lastLogonTimestamp, whenCreated |
Select DisplayName, givenName, sn, SamAccountName, Enabled,
    @{n="lastLogonDate";e={get-date ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)) -f MM/dd/yyyy}},
    @{n="Created";e={get-date ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.whenCreated)) -f MM/dd/yyyy}}| 
Export-CSV -NoType .\usrtst01.csv
```

But,The export goes like this:

"User test","User","test","user.test","True","04/01/2020",

However, if I use the code like this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * –Properties DisplayName, givenName, sn, SamAccountName, Enabled, lastLogonTimestamp, whenCreated |
Select DisplayName, givenName, sn, SamAccountName, Enabled,
    @{n="lastLogonDate";e={get-date ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)) -f MM/dd/yyyy}}, whenCreated | 
Export-CSV -NoType .\usrtst02.csv
```

The export:

"User test","User","test","user.test","True","04/01/2020","01/04/2020 8:28:31 AM"

The problem is that I need the format:

MM/dd/yyyy

Could you helpme please.

Thanks.

Comment: Because you aren't formatting the date string like in the first example, you're simply outputting `whenCreated`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lastLogonTimestamp` and `whenCreated` have are two different data types.

`lastLogonTimestamp` is represented as a large Integer, counting the ticks from 1.1.1601, hence you must convert it. You are doing that with `[datetime]::FromFileTime()`.

`whenCreated` in contrast is of format `datetime` that `Get-Date` can handle, but `[datetime]::FromFileTime()` cannot. If you invoke just that line, that doesn't work for you as expected you get a proper error.

```
get-date ([datetime]::FromFileTime("01/04/2020 8:28:31 AM")) -f MM/dd/yyyy

Cannot convert argument "fileTime", with value: "01/04/2020 8:28:31 AM", for "FromFileTime" to type "System.Int64": "Cannot convert value "01/04/2020 8:28:31 AM" to
type "System.Int64". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format.""
```

That's exactly what's breaking your command and leaving the output string blank.

Simply remove `[datetime]::FromFileTime()` and you're good to go.

```
get-date ("01/04/2020 8:28:31 AM") -f MM/dd/yyyy
```